# Facebook - How to see all users or friends of friends that use an app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following url will display a list of the user's friends that use the given app:

http://www.facebook.com/browse/friends_using_app/?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXX

where XXXXXXXXXXXXX is the id of the given app (any app id, not necessarily my own app).

This such url is found when looking at the app's profile page under the section of "Friends that use this app".

What I want to know is how can we get a similar list of ALL the given app's users or at the very least, the friends of the user's friends that use the given app?

For example, how could we see a list of all players that play FarmVille?

Answer (score -1):

There are ways to approximate this.

1) get read_stream permission, then read /me/home.  Some entries will have "application" nodes. Example:

```
 "application": {
    "name": "Facebook for Android", 
    "id": "350685531728"
  }
```

2) you can also get scores from games, but none of my friends had this:.

```
me/friends?fields=scores
```

Comment: I want to know all fans of any given page, not my own page nor limited to only my friends.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does not expose anything for friends-of-friends.  That would be considered a breach of the intermediary friends' privacy

Comment: But it isn't friends of friends: It is fans of a page, which should be consider "public". This information used to be available but since the switch this isn't available anymore.

Comment: The answer is the same.  What you are asking would be a serious breach or privacy.

Comment: Okay, all I'm saying is fan pages used to show all fans of that page but ever since Facebook made the switch the no longer can. It wasn't a privacy issue last year.